# Is there a way to make a creature be treated as a different alignment temporarily?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, alignment

I'm looking for a way (preferably by spell) to temporarily make an unwilling creature be treated as a different alignment, without actually permanently altering it. I'm looking for a way to have things like Smite Evil be able to affect them, or to have wielding an Axiomatic weapon give them a negative level.

I'm familiar with the Evil Domains' *Touch of Evil* power, and the Alchemists' *Change Alignment* discovery. I wanted to know if there was anything similar to these abilities that can temporarily alter how creatures are affected by spells/abilities based on their alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a temporary basis, the only spell I am aware of in Pathfinder 1e [*Baleful Polymorph*](http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/spells/balefulPolymorph.html#baleful-polymorph) spell.

> If the spell succeeds, the subject must also make a Will save. If this second save fails, the creature loses its extraordinary, supernatural, and spell-like abilities, loses its ability to cast spells (if it had the ability), and ***gains the alignment, special abilities, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores of its new form in place of its own***. It still retains its class and level (or HD), as well as all benefits deriving therefrom (such as base attack bonus, base save bonuses, and hit points). It retains any class features (other than spellcasting) that aren't extraordinary, supernatural, or spell-like abilities.

The big limitation on this, however, is that it transforms to a creature of small stature and 1 HD.

Comment: Well, not what I was hoping to find, but now I know.

Comment: @RevenantBacon - There are other methods, but they tend to be permanent, and/or require the willingness of the participant (Such as *atonement*).

Comment: To be fair, *Baleful Polymorph* seems pretty permanent.

Comment: @RevenantBacon - Dispel Magic will reverse it, as will a few other spells (Break enchantment, limited wish, etc). Most of the others are more permanent (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. What *I* meant when I said temporary was "having a duration that is shorter than 'until it gets removed'" though.

Comment: @RevenantBacon - I'm not aware of anything that is temporary like that for alignment. There are ways to mask alignment on a temp basis, but actually changing it tends to be pretty one way.